# How to reset 2d array keys in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How to reset the key value of an array? I have an array named $myArray like this :

```
Array([TF22] => Array([5] => 07.00 [6] => 09.45 [7] => 13.00)
      [TF23] => Array([8] => 07.00 [9] => 15.45))
```

how I can reset the array key like :

```
Array([TF22] => Array([0] => 07.00 [1] => 09.45 [2] => 13.00)
      [TF23] => Array([0] => 07.00 [1] => 15.45))
```

I have tried using array_value(), but the result :

```
foreach($myArray as $val) {
  $val = array_values($val);
}

Array([0] => 07.00[1] => 09.45[2] => 13.00)
Array([0] => 07.00[1] => 15.45)
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: `array_walk($myArray,function(&$value) {$value = array_values($value); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop like this...

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($yourarray as $k=>$arr)
{
 $new_arr[$k] = array_values($arr);
}
```